# Url encoding links in HTML email intermittently fails

Tags: c#, html

I'm generating links which are being emailed out to users of an application to have them verify and activate their account. I generate a token in this format `<email>|<guid>`, encrypt the token, URL encode it and then place it in a email.

```
 string verificationLink = activateUserFormUrl + "?" + QueryParamNameForToken + "=" +
                         HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Encryptor.Encrypt(username + "|" + token));
```

This token is then placed into an HTML email (the HTML is valid but only including the relevant portion)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
...
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
...
<p><a href="###verificationLink###">Activate my account</a>.</p>
```

This works fine for me and the majority of users to my site. However, for about 1% of users when they receive the link in their email, it isn't url encoded anymore. So when they click on the link, they get

```
https:/mysite/activate-account?actTkn=+thfPdJvWZggZmoHKznEiRV+i03uMv
```

instead of

```
https:/mysite/activate-account?actTkn=%2bthfPdJvWZggZmoHKznEiRV%2bi03uMv
```

As a result, the token isn't retrieved correctly for these users. I haven't been able to reproduce the issue and I've tested many variables to try to get to the bottom of the problem.

**Theory 1**

My first thought was that some generated tokens couldn't be URL encoded correctly using the `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` method. To test this, I was forwarded one of the messed up emails from the user and retrieved the invalid link.I URL encoded the token and decrypted it to get the contents. Then I stepped through the process of encrypting the same username and token, URL encoding it and emailing it to myself. However, when I received the email, it was URL encoded correctly and it worked fine.

So it doesn't appear as though it's a problem with the URL encoding itself.

**Theory 2**

I figured it must be a particular email provider. However, one of the users was using a gmail account when he received the invalid link. I tested with Gmail, Outlook, YOPMail and hotmail and in every case my email got to me still URL encoded correctly.

I don't think it's specific to an email provider but I'm wondering if there is possibly some setting that affects how HTML is interpreted on an account by account basis (?)

**Theory 3**

Failing that, I assumed some type of browser specific issue. I popped open my gmail in all versions of IE 8 and above, Chrome, Firefox and Safari but none of them replicated the issue.

**Other possibilities**

My leading theory now is that there is some antivirus or potentially a browser add on that is affecting the links.

Am I missing something? I've read around on Stackoverflow and found some similar issues but none of the questions have any answers. I'm fully open to any suggestions on a resolution. If I can get some assistance even recreating the issue, I can test some solutions.

Comment: what if you were to create a test url site and insted of encoding the url pass a link redirect from the email to that page..? this way you can at least narrow it down and from there it's probably some special characters that would need to be Encoded properly that's my suggestion
here is a good site to read as well [Email Confirmation](http://kevin-junghans.blogspot.se/2013/02/adding-email-confirmation-to.html)

Comment: I would remove the issue entirely by replacing `+` in your (presumably Base64) token with a character that does not need escaping and is not part of the Base64 alphabet, E.g. `_`

Comment: @DJKRAZE That's an interesting suggestion. The only drawback of the redirect URL is that I need to keep the URLs relatively secure so I would probably still need some encryption/hashing step to make enumeration difficult. I'll play around with this a bit and see what I can come up with.

Comment: @AlexK I have read some issues surrounding Url encoding base 64 characters so that seems likely. If I can get around encoding altogether I'm sure it will be more reliable. Thanks for the tip

Comment: Most mail clients will let you "show original" (gmail) or "view.. message source" (thunderbird) or some variation on them to view the original email as it was received and before the client started monkeying around with it. Might be that checking these will help shed some light on things.

Comment: Have you figured this out yet? I'm in the same situation now !
We use mailinator.com for testing and apparently they changed the way the url is encoded in the email and it doesn't work properly anymore